# Openfire vs ejabberd for customer service chat evolving to full chat solution

Tags: xmpp, openfire, ejabberd

I need to setup chat as a solution for customer service on a website. Openfire and some of it's plugins (fastpath and webchat) were very simple to setup locally and offer all of the customer service experience options I'd need, and will integrate properly into our CRM.

We have a clustered ejabberd instance running for something else. Before I looked into openfire, this was the obvious choice, since it's already been made secure and tailored to our environment. Having to duplicate all of the customer service functionality in an ejabberd module when it comes out of the box with openfire seems like a bad investment of resources.

Eventually, we would like to enable user to user chat as well, and perhaps turn it into a full scale messaging system.

Is it possible and/or recommended, using s2s or some other technique, to share the same database instance between the two different servers ? Does anyone else have any experience running both servers ? I'm sure there will be lots of gotchas if we go down this route, anything obvious ?

Comment: did found which one is best open fire or jabberd for chat solution?

Comment: We are going to use both. openfire/fastpath for customer service and ejabberd for peer chat/messaging.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i was obliged to move to openfire for compatibility reasons.
I have a user list in a sql-server database and the external authentification is really hard and not supported for updated versions of ejabberd.
For me openfire is more open to different database and easy to integrate in existing plateforms